# SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xfe' in file

Tags: python, кодировка

Большое кол-во времени писал на python 3.7, но стоило мне перейти на 3.10, у меня появилась ошибка.
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xfe' in file .
Как исправить эту проблему, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Код и полный стейк-трейс ошибки привести для начала. И подтвердить, что на 3.7 у вас её нет, а на 3.10 - есть (сомнительно, кстати, что так).

Comment: Кроме того, весь интернет пестрит советом добавить `# -*- coding: utf8 -*-` в файл. Вы его применяли?

Comment: Я обновил железо, до этого был 3.7 питон, сейчас 3.10

Comment: С кодингом пробовал добавлять, ничего не поменялось

Comment: Попробовал поменять кодировку всю в UTF-8 в пайчарме, получились вот такие вот символы: Exciton, ýëåêòðîìîíòàæíàÿ êîìïàíèÿ

Comment: Скорее всего у вас файл кода в кодировке cp1251: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEjFI.png. От перехода с 3.7 на 3.10 не должно было сломаться. Возможно где-то в процессе пересохранили в кодировке cp1251. Нужно теперь пересохранить в utf-8 (или указать `# -*- coding: cp1251 -*-` в начале файла, но лучше просто персохранить)

Comment: `\xfe` выглядит как начало BOM в кодировке UTF-16-BE